# Building Angular 5 with AOT is very slow and memory consuming

Tags: angular, angular5

I just migrated from Angular 4 to Angular 5, hoping to save some precious seconds every time my app rebuilds.

From https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced :

> Our goal was to make AOT compilation fast enough so that developers could use it for development, eliminating the differences that developers sometimes run into when trying to go to production for the first time. The team has hit its 2 second incremental AOT rebuild performance targets, and will be turning AOT on by default in a future release of the CLI.

Here is my new package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.5",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.26.11",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.77",
    "@types/quill": "^1.3.3",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-scroller": "^1.4.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
    "primeng": "^5.0.2",
    "quill": "1.2.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.5",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.45",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.18",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.4",
    "tslint": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
```

Now that the migration is done, I have serious performance issues when building / rebuilding my app. 
As suggested, I now use `ng serve --aot` to test my code.

The problem is :

- The first build takes > 2Go of RAM and is very slow
- The first incremental rebuild fails because of a `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Here is the result of an AOT build :

```
Hash: 042c05f2f5f6996535b7
Time: 536793ms
chunk {account.module} account.module.chunk.js () 29.7 kB
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 5.79 kB [entry]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 15.6 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 952 kB [initial]
chunk {projet.module} projet.module.chunk.js () 38.3 kB
chunk {rapport.module} rapport.module.chunk.js () 991 kB
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 3.14 MB [initial]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 13 MB [initial]

webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Did I missed something ? Is it really possible to use the AOT build in development ?

Comment: one thing I have used in similar situations is to run via the command "node --max-old-space-size=4096 ng serve --aot" (note that the 'ng' part may require a specific path specified - have seen that when running on windows)

Comment: Actually, I already got this problem when I was using Angular 4 and solved it using your solution. But with Angular 5 the cost is far more important and I don't have unlimited RAM.

Comment: The fact is that I'm far far away from this 2s to rebuild AOT incrementally. So far that my computer can't deal with it and fails.

Comment: Make sure you are on the latest version of node. Moving from node 6 to 8 made a huge difference

Comment: I migrated to Node 8.9.x, nothing changed. I edited my question to add the result of a build in my console. The last build lasted 536s !

Comment: Possibly related to the issue is that main.bundle.js (main) is 15.6 MB -  that is massive. Looks like you have some code splitting but likely need a lot more. Check out webpack-bundle-analyzer to reduce what is in that bundle https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer

Comment: I can't generate stats so I can't use your tool. Nevertheless, I used another one and finally 76% of the main.bundle.js is actually my code. Only 24% extra dependencies

Comment: If you separate out your code further into lazily loaded modules I think it would benefit both your users and the aot problem mentioned here.

Comment: Yes I think you're right. Maybe I just have to optimize my calls to the different modules of my app. I'll try this.

Comment: this makes for sad reading.  To honest, nobody wants to be spending time looking at ways to optimize calls to ensure that the system builds faster!  I hope there are better approaches...perhaps more memory in system.

Answer (score 1):

For the build being slow you can use this version of the angular cli:

"@angular/cli": "1.7.0-beta.0",

this cut my building time from 30 minutes to 3 minutes.

In Angular 5, AOT and build-optimizer are by default in prod builds.

`ng build --prod --named-chunks adding --named-chunks`.

to your build command will give you named chunks so you can better analyze you chunks, and better enhance what you are importing in each module. An example that maybe you are importing the whole shared module into a certain module while you just use one thing from that shared module

Comment: I think you might mean from 3 minutes to 30 seconds :-)

Comment: @fergal_dd no I meant what I said I have a very big app that used to take up to 45 minutes

Comment: Thx for the answer Nadhir. I will try the new release of the CLI. I'm not surprised you spend 30 min to build.. My app is currently building in 7mins.